# Push Notification not working in development

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Can't make push notification work with development certificate. I successfully register for push communication, but the push from server never comes. With production certificate works. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

When working with debug builds, you must use `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` as your APNS gateway, instead of the production one.

Comment: Thanks, I know this and I use it. What else should I check?

Comment: @AlexTau Make sure your debug provisioning profile is not a general `com.company.*` one but a full `com.company.app`.

Comment: Yes, this is also in place. I use an explicit bundle id.

Comment: @AlexTau What does the APNS feedback return?

Comment: I successfully register and I receive the push token which is then sent to my server.

Comment: Yes, but there is a feedback service which will tell you what the problem is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49191/discussion-between-alex-tau-and-leo-natan)